# Slow rendering of android layout : constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I've been looking for ways on how to flatten this view and still retain behavior such as swiperefresh and scroll. As it is currently it is very slow to render, it take about 7-8seconds to open up the fragment that host this view after a click of a list item.

The moment i remove the SwipeRefreshLayout down to the child ConstraintLayout rendering is fast, but then certain behavior such as scroll and swipe to refresh is lost. I don't know if there are alternatives to make it render faster.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.views">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView></TextView>
                <TextView></TextView>
                <TextView></TextView>
                ....

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </ScrollView>
   </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        app:menu_fab_size="mini"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="#adfafafa">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_material_utilization"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu_fab_size="mini"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_toolbox_white_18dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccentSecondary"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccentSecondary"
            fab:fab_label="Add Material Utilization"
            />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_request_material"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu_fab_size="mini"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_material_basked_white_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/below_average"
            fab:fab_label="Request Material"
            />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_update_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu_fab_size="mini"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black_svg_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/textColorSub"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/dividerColorSecondary"
            fab:fab_label="Update Status"
            />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure the 7-8 seconds are due to rendering? This seems way too long even if the layout is inefficient.

Comment: let's say about 5 seconds... But if i remove the scrollview majorly, it is fast in rendering.@Henry

Comment: Also note that this is without any data called from remote nor any call to findViewById

Comment: What's the purpose of these `TextViews` in the `ScrollView`? How many of them are there? Perhaps they should be changed to a `RecyclerView` if you're just listing stuff?

Comment: @plaskoff it is actually not same format of textview they look different so im not sure how to handle that in recyclerView, however indeed the textviews are pretty much as i later found out. so i've tried reducing it and also hiding some and making it visible at run-time.. i guess that is the best i can do, also the performance fairly okay now.

Comment: 5 seconds is still too much just for rendering. How many TextViews are you dealing with? Making some visible at run-time is not a solution. Please add your java code.

Comment: Also, don't forget to add SwipeRefreshLayout's constraints (Right_toRightOf, etc.).

Comment: @RamiJemli 48 TextViews and 8 View(Divider)

Comment: @PaulOkeke That's too much and that definitely should be a RecyclerView. So, add your full layout, and I will help with the multi type RecyclerView.

Comment: @RamiJemli I am dealing with something similar and could use some input see-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830623/constraintlayout-recycling-for-faster-performance